# Laravel - Transform data during migration

Tags: php, laravel-5, database-migration

Is it possible to transform a table's data during a migration? As an example, I would like to add a new column, but the default value isn't sufficient for existing data (the default value is fine for new records, but existing data already has a structure that needs to be put into the new field).

I would like to be able to do something like this:

```php
Schema::table('comments', function(Blueprint $table) {
    $table->unsignedInteger('level')->default(0);
    $table->text('lineage');
});

foreach (Comments::whereNotNull('parent_id')->get() as $c) {
    $c->level = $c->calculateLevel();
    $c->save();
}
```

so that 'level' doesn't have to be calculated on demand (it can be intensive if it's a long comment tree)

I *could* write a command which calculates and saves these level values, but it feels like something that should happen *with* the migration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I answered my own question in my example.

Once the schema has been changed, you can access the objects and use the new fields.

To re-iterate the answer:

```php
Schema::table('comments', function(Blueprint $table) {
    $table->unsignedInteger('level')->default(0);
    $table->text('lineage');
});

foreach (Comments::whereNotNull('parent_id')->get() as $c) {
    $c->level = $c->calculateLevel();
    $c->save();
}
```